# Sprites background not sizing properly in safari only on some computers

Tags: css, safari, background-image, sprite

I am currently working on a reponsive css webdesign and have a few sprites for different button states.

In this case I've tested the webdesign in Firefox, Opera, IE (compatibilty starting from IE8), Chrome and Safari and everything is displayed correctly. The website has been tested under different cell phones and tablets with different browsers without any problems.

I'm in the final testing stages and having co-workers see how the website looks in different resolutions... A friend who owns a macbook pro is the only one who encounters this problem and only under safari which makes it difficult for me to target and solve. I have tried to reproduce the problem using his screen size and switching safari's mode to that of a mac user without success.

The code is the following :

```
.buttons-menu .btn .rules, .buttons-menu .btn .contact , .buttons-menu .btn .tickets , .buttons-menu .btn .profile {  display: block; width: 143px;height: 32.5px;padding-top: 37.5px; background-size: 100% 300%;}
.buttons-menu .btn .rules {background: url(../images/sprite-button-03.png); background-position: 0 -100%;}
```

The problem is that this tester sees about 2 pixels of the second part of the sprite when he shouldn't and this only in safari.

Thank you for reading this.

EDIT : SOLUTION : As ralph.m thought, the problem came from the rounding of the decimals in safari that didn't always behave the same as in other browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid using values like `.5px`. The browser will have to round that up or down to a whole number, and you don't know which way it will go.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'm gonna try to change that and I'll come back to you when I get an answer from my co-worker.

Comment: This works, thanks a lot, I'll try to keep that in mind next time !